# How to compare Inputs and JSON data

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, error-suppression

I'm working on a school project and I need to validate some users without making a real Database. My problem is that when I compare the information entered in the inputs with the information storaged in JSON, it pops an error for every option that doesn't match. What I want is to reduce the multiple errors into only one (in case that the username or the password doesn't matches with the information storaged in JSON). Here is My JavaScript:

```js
const form = document.querySelector('form');

form.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
    
    const emailInput = document.querySelector('#email').value;
 const pwdInput = document.querySelector('#pwd').value;

 const object = {
  email: emailInput,
  pwd: pwdInput
 };

fetch('users.json')
  .then(res => res.json())
 .then(data => {
  data.forEach(function(user) {

   const userInfo = JSON.stringify(user);
   const databaseInfo = JSON.stringify(object);


   if(userInfo === databaseInfo) {
     console.log('success');
   } else {
    console.log('err');
   }

  });
 })

 .catch(error => console.log('error'));

});
```

And here is the fake database made with JSON:

```
     [
      {"email": "James", "pwd": "1111"},
      {"email": "Peter", "pwd": "2222"},
      {"email": "Josh", "pwd": "3333"}
     ]
```

Comment: it seems like you should be comparing the values instead of the objects. so something like `user.email === object.email && user.pwd === user.pwd)` your `JSON.Stringify` might be unnecessary too. Then for your only 1 error bit, you can add a boolean called found and set it to true if the above condition is true. Then outside the loop you check that var and if its `false` log a not found error

Comment: You need `==` not `===`. Example code: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/j3g950kq/

Comment: Hey! Thanks for replying, but I´m new with JavaScript and didn´t understand the last part you said about booleans. I tried this but didn´t worked:    if(user.email === object.email && user.pwd === object.pwd) {
     var flag = true;
     console.log('succ');
   } else if (flag = false) {
     console.log('err');
   }

Comment: @Santiago initialize the flag to false before the forEach loop, then if found set it to true. The next step is to just check it once outside the `forEach` loop `if( !flag ){ console.log("no match");}` this way you are not printing for every non-match, only once after the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using vanilla JavaScript :

```js
// This is only to simulate your fetch from JSON
function fakeFetch () 
{
  return Promise.resolve([
    {"email": "James", "pwd": "1111"},
    {"email": "Peter", "pwd": "2222"},
    {"email": "Josh", "pwd": "3333"}
  ]);
}

const form = document.querySelector('form');

form.addEventListener( 'submit', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
    
  const emailInput = document.querySelector('#email').value;
  const pwdInput = document.querySelector('#pwd').value;

  const object = {
    email: emailInput,
    pwd: pwdInput
  };

  fakeFetch()     
  .then( users => {
   
    // Check each user in users and try to find a match
    for ( let user of users )
    {
      // Destructuring email and password from the current user
      let { email, pwd } = user;
      
      // Comparing email and pwd from active user with the ones in object
      if ( email === object.email && pwd === object.pwd )
      {
        // Found, do something
        console.log( 'found!' );
        return;
      }
    }
    
    // Not found, do something else
    console.log( 'Not found...' );
    
  })
  .catch(error => console.log( error ) );

});
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="email"/>
  <input type="test" id="pwd"/>
  <input type="submit"/> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried explaining in the comments, but its probably easier to show you. I think its better to compare the smallest amount of data possible (rather than a big JSON string), like email to email and password to password.

So I changed your `if` to do a more simpler compare.

To condense all your errors into one, you can include a flag and set it to `true` if a match is found. Then outside the forEach loop you can check that flag and log just 1 error (if there is no match)

```js
var users = [{
  email: "user1",
  pwd: "pass1"
}, {
  email: "user2",
  pwd: "pass2"
}];

var object = {
  email: "user3",
  pwd: "pass3"
};

var isMatch = false;
users.forEach(function(user) {
  if (user.email === object.email && user.pwd === object.pwd) {
    console.log("success");
    isMatch = true;
  }
});

if (!isMatch) {
  // only logs once even though there are multiple users
  console.log("No Match!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main idea of your function is to, given a tuple (username, password), check if it exists in your database, which is an array of objects in this case.
You could say you want to filter from the array the entries whose username and password match what was inserted by the user. Since there should be no repeated tuples of username/password, your filter should either return the matching tuple or null.

An approach for this could be the following:

```js
function verifyLogin(loginObject) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fetch('users.json')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => data.filter(entry => entry.email ===
loginObject.email && loginObject.pwd === object.pwd).length > 0 ? resolve(true) : resolve(false))

      .catch(error => reject(error));

  });
})

}

verifyLogin(loginObject)
  .then(result => result === true ? console.log('Login successful!') : console.log('Login failed'))
  .catch(error => console.log(error))
```

This way the code shows what you are trying to accomplish and does it with no side effects.